# MS Access Query - Prompt for one parameter and pass to multiple subqueries

Tags: ms-access

I have two queries which take parameters:

[Hours Spent Table]:  [Enter Date]

[Hours Earned Table]: [Enter Start Date] [Enter End Date]

They are joined in another query which looks at productivity on one date. I'd like to run the query, enter a date, and have that date pass to all 3 parameters. Right now I'm being prompted for the date, start date, and end date (which are all the same for this query). Is there a way to do this in the SQL without having to create a form?

Thanks,

-Sean

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something on the lines of

```
 PARAMETERS adate DateTime;
 SELECT Stuff WHERE Somedate = [adate]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have one query which uses the following SQL: 

'WHERE [Supertable Query].[Final Comp]>=[start date] And [Supertable Query].[Final Comp]<=[end date]'

And another query which uses 

([Timesheet Sorting].Date)=[Enter date])

Comment: In that case, why do you not want to use a form?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have one query which uses the following SQL: 


'WHERE [Supertable Query].[Final Comp]>=[start date] And [Supertable Query].[Final Comp]<=[end date]'




And another query which uses 


([Timesheet Sorting].Date)=[Enter date])


Those two queries are linked in a third query which totals all progress and hours worked on a particular date. It prompts me for all 3 variables, but I was wondering if there was a way to have something along the lines of 


[start date]=[enter date]


[end date]=[enter date]

Comment: Add parameters to third query as illustrated above. You can use the property sheet in design view.

Comment: or something so it doesn't prompt me 3 times for 3 variables that are all the same. I need to keep the [start date] and [end date] variables because I use that query for other purposes where I need earned value over a number of days, so I can't just name the variables the same.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to explain it, but I don't think this solves the problem because even if I put in the [adate] parameter, it will still ask me for the [enter start date], [enter end date] and [enter date] parameters from the two subqueries. Now I have 4 parameters instead of 3 .. Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `PARAMETERS [enter date] DateTime;` Just use the names that suit you.

Comment: I'm already doing that. Query A (hours worked) uses [enter date] DateTime, Query B (hours earned) uses [enter start date] DateTime and [enter end date] DateTime. Now query C joins up the hours worked and hours earned from queries A and B. How would putting PARAMETERS [enter date] DateTime into query 3 tell Access not to prompt me for [enter start date] and [enter end date] when it goes into query B, and instead give them the value of [enter date]?